# Getting react state objects using spread or destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring, spread-syntax

It seems like there's a preferable reason to spread rather than destructure, but I'm not understanding why. Of course when writing/reading the code destructuring is much easier and less code, but some tutorials seem to prefer the spread, but in those examples they don't seem to be pulling 2 or more items from state. Seems weird to write:

```
let obj1 = {...this.state.obj1};
let obj2 = {...this.state.obj2};
let obj3 = {...this.state.obj3};
```

when this is so much cleaner

`let {obj1,obj2,obj3} = this.state;`

This is assuming that I plan to do something like this after getting these values

```
obj1.foo = "bar";
obj1.baz = "qux";
obj2.foo = "bar";
obj3.foo = "baz";
this.setState({obj1,obj2,obj3});
```

Why is one better than the other, and if spread is preferable is there a way to make the code cleaner?

Comment: *but in those examples they don't seem to be pulling 2 or more items from state* I'd call those bad tutorials then, IMO

Comment: The spread actually gives you the whole state object. Wheras in destructuring, you have specific obj assigned to that same variable name as in `{}` defined.

Both have different use cases. They aren't similar

Comment: @MeetZaveri I apologize, I wrote the spread syntax incorrectly. I meant to include the spread of each individual object. {...this.state.obj1} instead of {...this.state}

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate I wasn't able to get an answer here. Thanks to Reddit, I can now answer this question.

Spread creates a shallow copy. Destructuring creates a reference, which causes the state to be directly mutated. Always use spread when pulling from state to write back to state. Destructuring is fine when being used only to read from state.